# regex to check url not works

Tags: regex

i added below regex to check if it is url:

```
function checkurl(url){
var regex = /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/;
if(!$.trim(url).match(regex)){
        //alert("Not Valid Url");
        alert('Not Valid Url');
        return false;
}
```

this works for most of url but for below url it shows error:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEQi87xSIgU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([?=\/\w \.-]*)\/?$

                                              ^^          ^^
```

Try this.See demo.Added `?=` to character class.Also removed `*)*` which would result in catastrophic backtracking.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/7

Comment: Good to point out the [explosive trap](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html#example)! counted [100024 steps](https://regex101.com/r/fU8xE6/1) on OPs pattern + provided sample url :S

Comment: @SatishKumarSingh it will wokr for all.Did it fail for any?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add few more characters in your last character class to support **query string** i.e. `?`, `&`, and `=`:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([?=&\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG5iL6/1)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for that URL because it has a query string (`?v=wEQi87xSIgU`).

Add this before `$`:

```
(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?
```

This will match query strings, and hashes.